# How to create a service in Angular2?

Tags: angular, odoo-9

I am a beginner at angular2 , and I m building this app where  I am using this piece of code to fetch some data from Odoo database , and I just want to implement it in a service since the app is growing , but I didn't know how to do it the correct way , and I didn't know what to return :

here's the app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [OdooRPCService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  projectList;
  ngOnInit(){
    let self =  this;
    self.projectList = [];
    self.odooRPC.init({
      odoo_server: "https://demo9"
    });
    self.odooRPC.login('DB', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
      console.log('login success');
    }).catch( err => {
      console.error('login failed', err);
    })
    self.odooRPC.call('project.project', 'search_read', [], {}).then((projects:any) => {
      if(projects){
        self.projectList = projects;
      }
    })
  }
  constructor( private odooRPC: OdooRPCService){
  }}
```

and here's the projects.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {ProjectList}from'./projects';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';

@Injectable()


export class ProjectsService {
   public projectList;
  constructor(private projectsservice:ProjectsService, private http:Http, private odooRPC: OdooRPCService) {}

  getProjects(){

    let self =  this;
    self.projectList = [];
    self.odooRPC.init({
      odoo_server: "https://demo"
    });
    self.odooRPC.login('DB', 'admin', 'admin').then(res => {
      console.log('login success');
    }).catch( err => {
      console.error('login failed', err);
    })
    self.odooRPC.call('project.project', 'search_read', [], {}).then((projects:any) => {
      if(projects) {
        self.projectList = projects;
      })

     }
  }}
```

and the model projects.ts :

```
export interface ProjectList  {
    name:string;
}
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ProjectsService} from "./projects.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ProjectsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

thank you.

Comment: As you laid it out, they're just injectable classes. The thing to know is that you have to "provide" it. This is typically done in the module. By "providing" it (putting it in the "providers" part of the module API), you're basically telling the framework, "provide this class as an injectable service" meaning it will more or less behave as a singleton (technically, a "managed instance"). You can customize a number of things to get fancy as far as exactly how that service is provided, but the basic is just to add it to the "providers" array as-is, then inject it into components and use it.

Comment: I did that , it's just in the projectsList.service.ts , is it correctly done ? because I failed to complile it

Comment: Yeah it all looks more or less right to me. The one thing that usually trips up the neophyte Angular 2 dev is the whole "what is declaration/imports/exports/providers, it's confusing!" And it is. Curious though why you bother with the whole self/this thing. I know there was a reason to do that in the past, but with ES6 and whatnot now that should rarely be needed. But if you want to know what's broken, you have to post the errors. Most people won't go through your code letter by letter to see if there might be errors, they'll just say, "what's the error".

Comment: The main problem is that I didn't know how to call the service from my app.component.ts , beside the fact that I should import it and add the service in app.module.ts providers.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor

```
constructor(
  private projectsservice:ProjectsService,
  private http:Http,
  private odooRPC: OdooRPCService
) {}
```

you cannot inject ProjectsService inside ProjectsService (it self). I don't see any usage of it inside the class , so why are you injecting it ?

Please read ng2 docs: [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#prep-for-injection)

Comment: The constructor itself does nothing. The parameter simultaneously defines a private projectservice property and identifies it as a ProjectsService injection site.

Comment: No. it doesn't identifies it as ProjectsService. (Identification happens with @Injectable() ) Here (constructor) you are telling angular2 framework to inject objects in to this class. but you cannot inject a class inside it self.

Comment: You are right , I should add :  constructor(private projectsservice:ProjectsService) in the app.component.ts file , not the service , I was confused.

Comment: best way to learn is by making silly mistakes. please accept the answer

Comment: I did that , but it's not working either , there's something wrong with my projectService.ts , beside the constructor part :/ !